# PowerShell: how to scan every PSObject property name and replace a period character regardless of the depth?

Tags: json, mongodb, powershell

Using Powershell I'm reading in an arbitrary json document to store within MongoDB. This goes well until I encounter a json document that has a URL for an element name.  The URL contains a period "." which MongoDB doesn't allow as part of the element name.

The problematic json element can occur in multiple levels within the JSON document

```
{
    "ENCODER":  "Lavf58.42.100",
    "HTTP://YOUTUBE.COM/STREAMING/OTF/DURATIONS/112015":  "Segment-Count: 9\r\nSegment-Durations-Ms: 5339(r=7),2970,\r\n\r\n"
}
```

The error that is thrown is: Element name 'HTTP://YOUTUBE.COM/STREAMING/OTF/DURATIONS/112015' is not valid'

If I manually remove the period the data imports without an issue.

So, how do I scan every PSObject property name and replace the character regardless of the depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it for a single PSObject:

```bsh
# build the test data
$json = "{'aaa':'bbb', 'c.c':'ddd'}"
$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$data

# aaa c.c
# --- ---
# bbb ddd

# rename properties with a "." in their name
foreach( $property in $data.psobject.Properties )
{
    if( $property.Name.IndexOf(".") -ge 0 )
    {
        $data.psobject.Properties.Remove($property.Name)
        $data | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $property.Name.Replace(".", "_") -NotePropertyValue $property.Value
    }
}
$data

# aaa c_c
# --- ---
# bbb ddd
```

Note, removing and appending properties might change the 'natural' order of the properties, which could break code that depends on it. For example:

```
aaa c.c eee
--- --- ---
bbb ddd fff
```

becomes

```
aaa eee c_c
--- --- ---
bbb fff ddd
```

With that in mind, now all you need to do is traverse any nested properties that are also PSObjects and apply it to them recursively :-).